# How Can I Take A Small Portion Of A Displacement Mesh Without Changing The Displacement

Tags: displacement

I am currently trying to render out a mountain scene animation with the camera passing through the mountains. The problem is that I need the middle part of the scene (about the middle tenth of the plane) to be actually geometry.  If it is possible, I would like to be able to "cut out" the middle of the plane but keep its current displacement so that I can bake a smaller texture. The problem I run into is that whenever I try to scale the mesh in any way, the new geometry is scaled and/or changed.

Heres the Dropbox if it helps: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w7ektonnqbp27ev/The%20Flower.blend?dl=0

[image: The Mountains]

[image: The Mountains Scaled Down]

[image: The Mountains Scaled With Scale Applied]

Comment: I'm not into downloading files... Are you using UV texture coordinates?

Comment: Hello :). Why not just use the *Displacement modifier*, and apply it? So you then have a second mesh with real geometry.